# Where is the "systemless hosts" file under Magisk?

Tags: magisk, hosts

Where is the "systemless hosts" file? I normally just replace the `hosts` file in `/etc/` since I have a customized list. With the systemless hosts, I don't know which file to replace.

P.S., for the newer magisk, it is under `/system_root/etc`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file is in `/magisk/.core`.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, the point of that Magisk feature is to hide the `hosts` file from both apps and Android itself. That means you should be able to edit the `hosts` file with a file editor app, or use a hosts editor app, without it being aware of Magisk. You just have to turn the feature on and grant root to the app.

My `/etc/hosts` is identical to my `/magisk/.core/hosts`, and I only use a hosts editor app to edit it.